# Why does express allow defining functions with a called function?

Tags: node.js, express

Why does express allow defining functions with a called function? Normally if you are defining a function or passing as an argument you pass the function reference and not the call.

When I first saw middleware examples, I expected it to be:

```
app.use(express.json); 
app.use(express.urlencoded);
var myfunction = function() {};
app.use(myfunction);
```

but instead I see things like:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Notice the, parameter brace characters, `()` Are these called functions returning a function?

FYI VSCode doesn't follow the reference on these methods so I can't see what it's returning.

**UPDATE**:
I could call the function myself and check what the results are... brb...back my app is in the middle of work and not launchable.

Comment: I would assume consistency, since some of them also accept options. but you'd probably be better off asking the people who built them.

Comment: Functions can return other functions.  That's all that's going on.  `app.use` is not importing `express.json`.  It's importing the functions that `express.json()` returns.

Comment: @TimRoberts that makes sense. I was able to step into the code and see that. I've added a note on it

Answer (score 0):

You aren't "defining" anything there - you're calling the `use` function that should receive a function as its argument. Calling `express.json()` or `express.urlencoded()` returns such functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function `app.use()` and pass a function call as its argument (`express.json()`), the called function returns something, and this return value is applied to the argument behind the scenes.

So, when you call app.use(express.json()), you are effectively invoking express.json() which returns another function (the express middleware)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, calling the function app.use() and pass a function call as its argument (express.json()), the called function returns another function.

I added a call to it in my app and I was able to step into the function.

As the docs say and the code shows, it is a function that is returning another function, in this case it is embedded.

```
/**
 * Create a middleware to parse JSON bodies.
 *
 * @param {object} [options]
 * @return {function}
 * @public
 */

function json (options) {
  var opts = options || {}

  var limit = typeof opts.limit !== 'number'
    ? bytes.parse(opts.limit || '100kb')
    : opts.limit
  var inflate = opts.inflate !== false
  var reviver = opts.reviver
  var strict = opts.strict !== false
  var type = opts.type || 'application/json'
  var verify = opts.verify || false

  if (verify !== false && typeof verify !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('option verify must be function')
  }

  // create the appropriate type checking function
  var shouldParse = typeof type !== 'function'
    ? typeChecker(type)
    : type

  function parse (body) {
    if (body.length === 0) {
      // special-case empty json body, as it's a common client-side mistake
      // TODO: maybe make this configurable or part of "strict" option
      return {}
    }

    if (strict) {
      var first = firstchar(body)

      if (first !== '{' && first !== '[') {
        debug('strict violation')
        throw createStrictSyntaxError(body, first)
      }
    }

    try {
      debug('parse json')
      return JSON.parse(body, reviver)
    } catch (e) {
      throw normalizeJsonSyntaxError(e, {
        message: e.message,
        stack: e.stack
      })
    }
  }

  return function jsonParser (req, res, next) {
    if (req._body) {
      debug('body already parsed')
      next()
      return
    }

    req.body = req.body || {}

    // skip requests without bodies
    if (!typeis.hasBody(req)) {
      debug('skip empty body')
      next()
      return
    }

    debug('content-type %j', req.headers['content-type'])

    // determine if request should be parsed
    if (!shouldParse(req)) {
      debug('skip parsing')
      next()
      return
    }

    // assert charset per RFC 7159 sec 8.1
    var charset = getCharset(req) || 'utf-8'
    if (charset.slice(0, 4) !== 'utf-') {
      debug('invalid charset')
      next(createError(415, 'unsupported charset "' + charset.toUpperCase() + '"', {
        charset: charset,
        type: 'charset.unsupported'
      }))
      return
    }

    // read
    read(req, res, next, parse, debug, {
      encoding: charset,
      inflate: inflate,
      limit: limit,
      verify: verify
    })
  }
}
```

Specifically, this line:

```
function json (options) {
    // ...
    return function jsonParser (req, res, next) { }
}
```